# Terraform: snowflake_grant_privileges_to_role:How to provide grants to table to share

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: To provide grants on the list of tables to share_name

Original Deprecated Resource :

**OLD_WAY**

```
resource "snowflake_table_grant" "grant" {
        for_each      = local.select_flat
    
        database_name = each.value.database_name
        schema_name   = each.value.database_name
        table_name    = each.value.table_name  
    
        privilege         = "SELECT"
        roles             = [snowflake_role.role.name]
        shares            = [snowflake_share.share.name]
    
        on_future         = true
        with_grant_option = false
    }

    locals {
      select_flat = merge(flatten([
        for database_name, schemas in var.select: [
          for schema_name, tables in schemas: {
              for table_name in tables: 
                "${database_name}-${schema_name}-${table_name}" => {
                     "database_name" = database_name
                     "schema_name" = schema_name
                     "table_name" = table_name
                 }                 
          }
        ] 
      ])...)
    }
```

From the Terraform resource, I don't see a full example of using shares in providing grants to a list of tables, schemas, and databases as in the above `select_flat`

Below is the syntax code from Terraform, I am not sure about the syntax

**NEW_WAY:**

```
resource "snowflake_grant_privileges_to_role" "g12" {
      privileges = ["SELECT"]
      role_name  = snowflake_role.r.name
      on_schema_object {
        all {
          object_type_plural = "TABLES"
          in_schema          = "\"my_db\".\"my_schema\""
        }
      }
    }
```

I need help with how to grant a list of the tables access to share, not all the tables

Comment: I think you need to use snowflake_table_grant

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/grant_privileges_to_role

You have to use the below to grant privileges on a specific object(table/view/schema/database) to a role.

```
##################################
### schema object privileges
##################################

# list of privileges
 resource "snowflake_grant_privileges_to_role" "g9" {
 privileges = ["SELECT", "REFERENCES"]
 role_name  = snowflake_role.r.name
      on_schema_object {
           object_type = "VIEW"
           object_name = "\"my_db\".\"my_schema\".\"my_view\"" # note this is a fully qualified name!
                       }
                                                     }
```

Comment: thanks , What about the share.name 
` shares            = [snowflake_share.share.name]`